# Changing the color of buttons in a grid in kivy

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, kivy

I'm having this problem where I can't change the color of my buttons in a grid while still keeping a separate background. If I change the button colors without using
`background_normal: ''`

I get the ugly grey tint but if I do use that, the background grid the buttons are on gets the same color as the buttons and you can do longer tell the buttons apart from each other. Here's the full code for the buttons and the grid they're in:

```
<Actions@Button>:
    text_align: "left"
    valign: "top"
    size_hint: 1, 0.2
    text_size: self.size
    font_size: self.height * 0.45
    padding_x: int(self.width * 0.03)
    padding_y: (self.height * 0.2)
    color: 0, 0, 0
    background_color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#c9deff')
    background_normal: ''

<SecondScreen@Screen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        GridLayout:
            cols: 4
            size_hint: 1, 0.44
            StackLayout:
                orientation: "lr-tb"
                spacing_hint: 0.1, 0.1
                size_hint: 0.3, 1
                minimum_width: self.parent.width * 0.3
                Actions:
                    text: "A"
                    on_press: root.manager.current = 'first'
                Actions:
                    text: "B"
                    on_press: root.manager.current = 'first'
                Actions:
                    text: "C"
                    on_press: root.manager.current = 'first'
```

This has really been impeding my progress on this UI. I've tried to put white rectangles on the grid and the original screen with `canvas.before` to see if that gives a white background but it all gets overwritten by the background color and ends up with the same mono-color block result. Couldn't find any references to this problem on the net either thus far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using `spacing` in your `StackLayout`, instead of `spacing_hint`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay it seems this question doesn't have any eyes or answers on it so the workaround I found was to use the `canvas` property to create a line around each button like this:

```
        Color:
            rgba: utils.get_color_from_hex('#0e1928') 
        Line:
            rectangle: (self.pos[0], self.pos[1], self.size[0], self.size[1])
            width: 1.15
```

And for labels like this:

```
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: utils.get_color_from_hex('#edf1ff')
                    Rectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos
                    Color:
                        rgba: utils.get_color_from_hex('#0e1928')
                    Line:
                        rectangle: (self.pos[0], self.pos[1], self.size[0], self.size[1])
                        width: (self.height * 0.004)
```

Nothing else I tried worked and this solution also has some issues like clipping into other buttons a bit but with a low width that problem was basically negligible. Anyway leaving this here in case any one else has issues with this later on. Which seems likely since all the most of the kivy tutorials I could find on youtube only show how to change the colors and presentations of single buttons or how to order many buttons in a layout. They don't show the two combined and so you don't see the problems that can pop up.